# Java Calculator Stack

Tags: java, calculator, stack

So my assignment is to design a simple GUI calculator using the stack data structure to perform additions, subtractions, multiplications and divisions. The calculator window should have at least two panels - one for display and the other for buttons (0 - 9, . , +, -, X, /, =, C). After an expression is entered, its postfix or prefix is displayed and then the result.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Stack;

public class JCalculator implements ActionListener {
JFrame jfrm;
JFrame jfrm2;
JTextField txt;
JLabel results;
String str = "";
Stack operands = new Stack();
char[] a = new char[0];
int used = 0;



JCalculator(){
    jfrm = new JFrame("JCalc");
    jfrm.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
    jfrm.setSize(210,210);

   results = new JLabel("",SwingConstants.RIGHT);
   jfrm.getContentPane().add(results);
   jfrm.setLocation(400,300);
   jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

   JButton[] calbut= new JButton[14];
   String []but = {"7","8","9","/","4","5","6","*","1","2","3","-","0","C"
   };
   JButton equal = new JButton("=");
   JButton add = new JButton("+");

   JPanel jbutton = new JPanel();
   jbutton.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3));
   for(int i=0; i< but.length;i++){
       jbutton.add(calbut[i] = new JButton(but[i]));

       calbut[i].addActionListener(this);
   }
   jbutton.add(equal);
   jbutton.add(add);

   equal.addActionListener(this);
   add.addActionListener(this);

   jfrm.getContentPane().add(jbutton);


    jfrm.setVisible(true);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
    char[] a = new char[0];
    int used = 0;
    if(used == a.length){
        char[] newa= new char[a.length + 1];
        for(int i = 0; i <used; i++) newa[i]= a[i];
        a= newa;
    }

    if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("1")){
        str = results.getText();
        results.setText(str + "1");
        operands.push(1);
    }
    if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("2")){
        str = results.getText();
        results.setText(str + "2");
        operands.push(2);
    }
    if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("3")){
        str = results.getText();
        results.setText(str + "3");
        operands.push(3);
    }
    if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("4")){
        str = results.getText();
        results.setText(str + "4");
        operands.push(4);
    }
    if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("5")){
        str = results.getText();
        results.setText(str + "5");
        operands.push(5);
    }
    if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("6")){
        str = results.getText();
        results.setText(str + "6");
        operands.push(6);
    }
    if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("7")){
        str = results.getText();
        results.setText(str + "7");
        operands.push(7);
    }
    if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("8")){
        str = results.getText();
        results.setText(str + "8");
        operands.push(8);
    }
    if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("9")){
        str = results.getText();
        results.setText(str + "9");
        operands.push(9);
    }
    if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("0")) {
        str = results.getText();
        results.setText(str + "0");
        operands.push(0);
    }
    if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("+")){
        str = results.getText();
        double operand = Double.parseDouble(str);
        operands.push(operand);
        results.setText("");
        a[used]= '+';
        used++;

    }
    if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("-")){
        str = results.getText();
        double operand = Double.parseDouble(str);
        operands.push(operand);
        results.setText("");
        a[used]= '+';
        used++;
    }
    if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("/")){
        str = results.getText();
        double operand = Double.parseDouble(str);
        operands.push(operand);
        results.setText("");
        a[used]= '+';
        used++;
    }
    if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("*")){
        str = results.getText();
        double operand = Double.parseDouble(str);
        operands.push(operand);
        results.setText("");
        a[used]= '*';
        used++;
    }
    if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("=")){

        for(int i = 0; i< used; i++){
           performBinaryOp(a[i]);
        }

        str = String.valueOf(operands.pop());
        results.setText(str);
    }


}
 public void performBinaryOp(char nextOperation) {
     double leftOperand, rightOperand;
    Double result = new Double(0);
    rightOperand = (Double) operands.pop();
    leftOperand = (Double) operands.pop();
    switch (nextOperation) {
        case '+':
            result = new Double(leftOperand + rightOperand);
            break;
        case '-':
            result = new Double(leftOperand - rightOperand);
            break;
        case '*':
            result = new Double(leftOperand * rightOperand);
            break;
        case '/':
            result = new Double(leftOperand / rightOperand);
            break;
    }
    operands.push(result);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new JCalculator();                
        }            
    });        
}
}
```

The error that I run into is when pressing the equals button, for example pressing 2+3= it return the first value 2.0 then I receive an error saying:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.EmptyStackException
at java.util.Stack.peek(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Stack.pop(Unknown Source)
at JCalculator.actionPerformed(JCalculator.java:152)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm pretty sure my problem is that I have an empty stack, but I'm not sure where the code is wrong or how to fix it, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking to get the whole application fixed or the current error to be addressed? If you are trying to address current issue, add a line to check if operands are empty before poping from that stack.

Basically change the handler for "=" as:
 

      `if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("=")){
            if(operands.isEmpty())
             return;`

Comment: I'm looking to get the whole application to fixed, are you saying i have more errors? :/

Comment: No Errors per se,but the calculator will not really "calculate"

Comment: yeah I just tried it and 2+3 does not equal 2 lol, thanks for your help on fixing the error

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend that you put Swing and UI aside until you have your calculator working properly.  Create a separate Calculator class that can take in text strings and evaluate them.  Once you have that working, then add a UI.

Yes, you've got a stack problem, just as the exception tells you:

```
at JCalculator.actionPerformed(JCalculator.java:152)
```

Open up your JCalculator in a text editor, turn on line number display, and go to line 152.  That's where your problem is.

I'm not willing to read through the code you posted, but I'd say that a quick spin with a debugger ought to clear it up pretty quickly.

Comment: alright thanks i'll take a look at it and try your suggestion out, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Your `actionPerformed()` method [shadows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) some of the class variables; note that you've re-declared `char [] a` and `int used`, and thus your code is almost certainly not behaving as you expect. I have not followed this to its logical conclusion.

```
public class JCalculator implements ActionListener {
JFrame jfrm;
JFrame jfrm2;
JTextField txt;
JLabel results;
String str = "";
Stack operands = new Stack();
char[] a = new char[0];
int used = 0;
/* ... */
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
    char[] a = new char[0];
    int used = 0;
    if(used == a.length){
        char[] newa= new char[a.length + 1];
        for(int i = 0; i <used; i++) newa[i]= a[i];
        a= newa;
    }
```

This section of code makes me think that you do not accept two-digit numbers:

```
if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("1")){
    str = results.getText();
    results.setText(str + "1");
    operands.push(1);
}
```

The `operands.push(1)` maybe needs to push the *number* that is being built, not just the most recent digit. (of course, if your intention is to only support single-digit numbers, this looks alright.)

I'd suggest trying to replace those ten little `if` statements with a single function. It's well worth taking the time to figure out a single function here, it'll drastically simplify maintenance of this code in the future and the skill is *vital*. (I'd like to suggest that you consider your neat `JButton` initialization earlier -- and try to use arrays in your replacement function. It might not be *best*, but it ought to be alright.)

```
if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("/")){
    str = results.getText();
    double operand = Double.parseDouble(str);
    operands.push(operand);
    results.setText("");
    a[used]= '+';
    used++;
}
```

You'll note that your `a[used]` is assigned the *wrong symbol*. Once you fix your variable shadowing issue, *this* will be an issue. Try to figure out a way to replace these four `if` blocks with another single function -- again, it will make it harder to make mistakes like this when adding new operators to your calculator and it will make fixing bugs in the operator-apply code far easier, because you only need to fix a bug in one location.

I cannot stress strongly enough how useful it is to break your code apart into "smallest reasonable" functions. You can test small functions far easier than large functions, and your code will be easier to read in the future.

Comment: thank you for the helpful tips and ideas, i'll definitely try to fix up my code.

Comment: My pleasure, happy programming. :)

Answer (score -1):

Just in case you need help with the calculator, here is one of my first projects in Java

https://github.com/orefalo/ExpressionEvaluator